# jsPDF conditional rendering

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have a super simple HTML file, no node, no packages. In my HTML I have several inputs. I only want input values to render into PDF, if they are not empty :

```
if (storiesCosts.value !='' || storiesCosts.value != '0') {
  pdf.text(10, 77, 'Kosten für Stories: ');
  pdf.text(70, 77, `${storiesNumber.value} Stories für ${storiesCosts.value} € `);
}
    
if (postsCosts.value !='' || postsCosts.value != '0') {
  pdf.text(10, 84, 'Kosten für Posts: ');
  pdf.text(70, 84, `${postsNumber.value} Posts für ${postsCosts.value} € `);
}
```

Well first of all, these conditions get ignored I get empty values rendered into my pdf. Secondly, how do I arrange texts on page, as if elements before won't render, the next element needs to have a higher position. Is there kind of forlmula, calculating y-position based on previous element?